# need to know the use of different pem keys

Tags: mysql, ssl

To connect to a remote mysql server over ssl, we need to create  following keys

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.7K Oct 29 15:21 ca-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.3K Oct 29 15:21 ca.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.2K Oct 29 15:21 client-cert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.7K Oct 29 15:21 client-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  993 Oct 29 15:21 client-req.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.2K Oct 29 15:21 server-cert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.7K Oct 29 15:21 server-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  993 Oct 29 15:21 server-req.pem
```

To establish a secured connection

```
mysql -u balaji_sri -pXXX --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem -h 18.221.222.23
```

```
I understand how web ssl works. 
(
*servers pub key is encrypted with CA'S private key which is shared to client as ssl key
*browser has all CA'S public key. browser decrypts and gets servers pub key
*client generates a random number and encrypts with servers public key
*server is able to decrypt that with its own private key
*rest of connection is handled with symmetrical encryption with the random number
)
```

In a similar way can some body explain what is the role of each of the keys mentioned above. (ca-key.pem, ca.pem, client-cert.pem, client-key.pem, client-req.pem, server-cert.pem, server-key.pem, server-req.pem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might find more interest in [crypto.SX](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) or [security.SX](https://security.stackexchange.com). Anyway,

> *servers pub key is encrypted with CA'S private key which is shared to client as ssl key

Hum... No.
Using public key encryption algorithms, one encrypts with a public key, and decrypts with a private key. **No one can encrypt with a private key**. If the public key algorithm also supports digital signature (RSA for instance), one can sign using its private key, and everybody can verify the signature using the signer's public key (similarly, you cannot sign using a public key).

As per your question, my guess is the following (items re-ordered):

- `ca-key.pem`: private key of the certification authority (should be encrypted!)
- `ca.pem`: root certificate of your authority (self signed with `ca-key.pem`)
- `client-key.pem`: private key of the client
- `client-req.pem`: request for signature from the certification authority (aka. csr)
- `client-cert.pem`: response from the certification authority to the previous request
- `server-key.pem`: same as `client-key.pem`, but for the server
- `server-req.pem`: same as `client-req.pem`, but for the server
- `server-cert.pem`: same as `client-cert.pem`, but for the server

You might be interrested in following [this tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html) to get a better understanding of X509 certificates.